# How do I figure out which server has least load on it?

Tags: php, time, load, response, ping

I'm building a software where a device connects to a defined point A (server). Point A need to connect to Point B (some server on The Internet). Point B exists several places across the Internet. Before Point A connects to a Point B it wants to figure out which one is the most responsive / less load on it.

Would a good way of figuring out which Point B to connect be to ping each URL and pick the one with the least response time?

I'm using PHP running on an Ubuntu server. Each point be is also PHP running on Ubuntu servers.

Comment: AWS elastic load balancer

Comment: No, I need Points B to be on completely different servers and each Point B will be owned and operated by independent parties.

Comment: install a script of every point B that reports its load perodiccly

Comment: I played with that idea. Bu for each unique device there is a defined Point A. Each of these point A's could reside anywhere on the web too. That means every Point B would have to report their load to every Point A. I estimate that there will be a couple of thousand Point Bs but potentially millions of Point As.

Comment: all the point B's report load to one point, all the A's ask that point which B has the lowest load.

Comment: You're going to spend more time trying to determine which server has more or less load than the others than you'll save routing requests to the less loaded server. Spread the requests evenly using a round-robin method.

Answer (score 0):

I am going to make the assumption, that while you do not control Point B servers, you do at least control the protocol they implement or otherwise provide software that is running on Point B servers.  Additionally I am assuming that Point B servers are not equal in capacity.  I am going to ignore your use of PHP, although it's lack of background threads (not familiar with PHP based options to overcome this) will cause issues with the following approach.

The server(s) at Point A should periodically be making a health request (multiple times a minute potentially) as an asynchronous request to each system in the available Point B pool.

What a health check contains varies, ideally the Point B server should indicate how many available requests it can handle in total and how much of that capacity is currently in use.  This could be seen in a webserver typically as how many parallel threads it is configured to process.

For your sanity I would suggest looking at something like [HAProxy](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/) between Point A systems and the pool of Point B systems.  Really any [load balancing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load_balancing_%28computing%29) system would be correct.